# CSS on HTTPS link in google chrome not applying proeprly

Tags: css, asp.net, google-chrome, ssl, https

CSS on a page secured with SSL (HTTPS) not applying properly. 
Its working fine on Mozilla and internet explorer but not working fine on chrome. 
I tried to call external css file using java-script based on protocol, but no success.

Comment: Your link is broken, I think you are missing the `www` from the start of the url, but ideally you should be providing code in the question rather than a link to a site.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall by any chance?

Comment: @Andy, link is working fine, its opening fine in all browsers.

Comment: @yadavr Not in my version of chrome. I get taken [here](https://viauphotography.com/Login.aspx) with a message saying 'webpage is not available'

Comment: there is a firewall, but CSS is working fine in other browsers except chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when accessing your CSS file over HTTPS, you are redirected to the HTTP version, and so the browser will block the file as it is not served sercurely.

You need to make sure you do not redirect back to HTTP for static resources.

Comment: @yadavr It seems as though on your site you have some code to redirect HTTPS back to HTTP if you are not on the `login.aspx` page, if this is the case you can also add an exception for CSS files.

Comment: Its not redirecting to HTTP, you can check it in another browser, either in Mozilla or IE. If you are talking about CSS file then yes its redirected to HTTP

Comment: @yadavr I'm getting the same in every browser I test it in, including firefox and IE. If you try and access [style.css](http://www.viauphotography.com/style.css) via HTTPS, it redirects to HTTP

Comment: Yes, i find it now, its redirecting to HTTP.

Comment: thanks @Andy, i allowed https access to CSS file in web.config file and now its working fine.

Comment: this is what i did -

"<secureWebPages mode="On" maintainPath="False">  
  <file path="Login.aspx" secure="True" />  
  <file path="style.css" secure="True" />
  <file path="/js/scripts.js" secure="True" />
  <file path="jquery.min.js" secure="True" />  
</secureWebPages>"

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config file in the web directory and change

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://myweb.com'), 
define('HTTP_CATALOG, 'http://myweb.com');
```

to: `https://myweb.com`